# django localflavor USStateSelect() inital value

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-localflavor

I'm trying to use the django localflavor widget USStateSelect() in a form, but I want the widget to have Nebraska selected by default.  The Widget only accepts an attrs arg, so I'm trying to understand what attributes I have to set to get the desired result.  Here's what I've got in my forms.py:

```
state = forms.CharField(widget=USStateSelect(attrs={'value':'NE'}))
```

This is the docs for the HTML select element: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/forms.html#the-select-element

This is the docs for localflavor: https://django-localflavor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/localflavor/us/forms/

```
<option value="NE" selected>Nebraska</option>
```

This is what I need to have in my html, but I can't figure out what the attrs dict needs to contain to achieve this result.  I've tried adding 'selected':'selected' and 'class':'selected' to the dict, but that's not doing it.

I've seen a number of people asking how to add an empty option, but no one seems to want to make it default to a specific state.  Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks,

Anthony

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the initial value like so:

```
state = forms.CharField(widget=USStateSelect(), initial='NE')
```

or you can set it when you instantiate the form:

```
form = ExampleForm(initial={'state': 'NE'})
```