# Specify default state for django-localflavor's USStateSelect field?

Tags: python, django, django-localflavor

I am working on a Django project and using django-localflavor to implement state selection into my app. My user base will primarily be located in New York state. Is there a way to specify NY as the default state for the USStateSelect widget (and just let users select any other state from the drop-down as needed)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21790543/django-localflavor-usstateselect-inital-value